# How to add new value to a list without using 'append()' and then store the value in a newly created list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been trying this a lot.

```
>>> x = [4,5]
>>> y = x.append(7)
>>> print y
None
>>>print x
[4, 5, 7]
```

How is this possible?

When I trying storing the values in the new list `y` and the print it, it results in `None` and it also changes the current list `x.

Is there any other way to do this in Python?

Comment: You can't do that, just do `y = 7` then `x.append(y)`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because the function `append()` modifies the list and returns `None`.

One of the best practices to do what you want to do is by using `+` operator.

Let's take your example :

```
>>> x = [4, 5]
>>> y = x + [7]
>>> x
[4, 5]
>>> y
[4, 5, 7]
```

The `+` operator creates a new list and leaves the original list unchanged.

Comment: Thanks. While this is the only solution I've seen to this, but I'm not fond of it. First, it simply __looks__ like a total hack. Second, it seems like we are constructing __two__ lists: one temporary list for containing the new value and then use __that__ into constructing the final list. A "real" solution would construct __one__ new list and add all values to that. I like python, but the notion that lists doesn't return even itself when using `append` (and other funcs) is a real pet peeve to me.

Answer (score 7):

This is possible because `x.append()` is a method of list `x` that mutates the list in-place. There is no need for a return value as all the method needs to do is perform a side effect. Therefore, it returns `None`, which you assign your variable `y`.

I think you want to either create a copy of `x` and append to that:

```
y = x[:]
y.append(7)
```

or assign `y` the result of a list operation that actually creates a new list:

```
y = x + [7]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do

```
x = [4,5]
y = x + [7]
# x = [4, 5]
# y = [4, 5, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `y` is `None` because the `append()` method doesn't return the modified list (which from your code you are expecting).

So you can either split the statement,

```
y = x.append(7)
```

into

```
x.append(7)
y = x
```

OR use,

```
y = x + [7]
```

The second statement is more cleaner and creates a new list from `x`.

Just a note: Updating `y` won't make any updates in `x` as in the first statement it does. If you want to avoid this use `copy.copy`

Answer (score -1):

Using Extend,

```
x = [3,4]
y =[]
y.extend(x+[7])
print(x, y)
```

produces output :

```
[3, 4] [3, 4, 7]

[Program finished]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
n=[4,7,9,1,56]  #original list
n=n+[100] 

print(n)
```

Comment: Why do you prefer this over the existing answers?